# Detection of dynamic allocation with the new operator C++

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, destructor

Is `new` the only operator that allows us to detect dynamic memory allocation in C++?

I'm asking this because I want to release all dynamic memory allocations for the destructor of my class.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect dynamic memory allocation"? If you use `new`, it must be matched with `delete` (and the same for `new[]` and `delete[]`). And do you really need manual and explicit memory handling at all? Consider [the standard smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers) or `std::vector` for "dynamic arrays". And in some cases, pointers can be avoided completely. If this is one such case we don't know since you don't give us any context or information.

Comment: Detecting memory allocations in `operator new` and their release in a destructor would likely be wrong design, since you wouldn't be able to "remember" types of constructed objects. How would you want to destruct them properly in the destructor?

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++ you keep heap references using `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`. They will free memory automatically when they are destroyed or when you manually `reset()` them.